# Change specific table prefixes on a subdomain in a wordpress multisite single install

Tags: database, wordpress, woocommerce, multisite

**Goal:**

Create a dashboard on a separate "my-account" sub-domain for customers to manage woocommerce account information while maintaining all other table prefixes to enable management of other information that is kept on the "my-account" subdomain.

**Issue**

I'm on a single install multi-site setup, and while I would normally edit the wp-config file to change the table prefix on a single site setup and write some redirects to ensure that all woocommerce links other than those dealing with the customer account would redirect to the shop domain, I'm unsure how to do so in my current setup, as there is only one wp-config.php file.

I apologize for any ignorance, I'm still new to WordPress multi-site setups.